# How to solve Dropdown Menu error and doesn't show?

Tags: html

Here I use a bootstrap template, but the dropdown menu can't be opened ... I'm still a beginner and I don't understand how to fix it, what is the solution to my problem?

```
<!-- Navigation-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#!">MITRA JAYA FURNITURE</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-lg-4">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#!">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#!">Tentang Kami</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" href="#!" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Kategori</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">All Products</a></li>
                            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Popular Items</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">New Arrivals</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#!">Tentang Kami</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">
                        <i class="bi-cart-fill me-1"></i>
                        Cart
                        <span class="badge bg-dark text-white ms-1 rounded-pill">0</span>
                    </button>
                </form>
                 <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 ms-lg-4">
                 <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="login.php">Login</a></li>
             </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Why doesn't the dropdown box show? Here is you can see more of the code with preview HERE https://jsfiddle.net/laelza/yq68dok5/1/

Please do tell me where I am wrong. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Please, check what version of Bootstrap you use!

Comment: bootstrap version 5.1.0

Comment: If you haven't already, you should probably review https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/ and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/ - most of Bootstrap's interactive widgets require JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

It seems like You forgot to add JS code of bootstrap:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js
```

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/8e3y6Lfv/

Comment: I've updated the script for the html at https://jsfiddle.net/laelza/4aq6fh7L/ but it seems the dropdown menu in the category can't be opened

Comment: @laelza please check console for errors. You should fix Your html code.